# Qt serial port lost sometimes the last byte

Tags: c++, qt

I am making RPM counter GUI with Qt, and arduino, i am using cooling fun to get the RPM values.
I am using the serial port to read the values from arduino, but sometimes i miss the last byte from the value that i print in Qt GUI, but i dont have the same problem in the arduino serial monitor. Here is the code from Qt :

```
void ArduinoRpm::serialReciver()
{

    QString input_converter;
    std::string to_file_string;

    int sizeFromInput = 0;
    char *dataBuffer;

    //get the port size depending on bytes available to read
    int bufferSize = serial->bytesAvailable();
    //int bufferSize = serial->bytesAvailable();

    //dataBuffer, get the data from serial port, bufferSize + 1 for the newline
    dataBuffer = new char[bufferSize + 2];

    //flush the port before read


    //This function reads a line of ASCII characters from the device, up to a maximum of
    //maxSize - 1 bytes, stores the characters in dataBuffer, and returns the number of bytes
    //read. if a line could not be read but no error ocurred, this function returns 0. if an
    //error occurs, this function returns the length of what could read or -1 if nothing was read.
    //bufferSize is the maxsize readline can read.

    sizeFromInput = serial->readLine(dataBuffer, bufferSize);

    //to_file_string, to write data in file
    to_file_string = dataBuffer;
    input_converter = QString::fromStdString(to_file_string);


    if ((sizeFromInput >= 1) && (input_converter.toInt() <= 9999)) {
        if(input_converter.toInt() > 10) {
            ui->lcdNumber->display(input_converter);
            rpmNeedle->setCurrentValue(input_converter.toInt());
            input_file << to_file_string << std::endl;
        }

    }

    delete dataBuffer;
    bufferSize = 0;
    serial->flush();

}

 void ArduinoRpm::SerialInitializer()
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    serial->setPortName(serialPortValue); //COM-port your Arduino is connected to
    serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600); //must be the same as your arduino-baudrate
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
}
```

for example

```
27
1621
1621
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1627
1621
1616
1616
1605
1605
1599
1594
1588
158
1583
158
1578
1578
1572
1572
1572
```

it should read 4 digits all the time, but sometimes it losts the last digit..
Any solution for this ?

Comment: and where is your `serialReciver` function called?

Comment: i have this statement in the main Consructor    connect(serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(serialReciver()));

Comment: *it should read 4 digits all the time*, why does the first line contain 2 digits only then??

Comment: for some reason it's chopped, from 1627 , this happens only in the first line when the arduino starts

Comment: does arduino serial monitor show 1627 in the beginning? or does it show just 27?

Comment: it shows 1627, seems the problem is in my code.. i dont know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

your function should be something like this:

```
void ArduinoRpm::serialReciver()
{
    char dataBuffer[6];

    if(!serial->canReadLine()) //if there isn't a whole line available
        return; //return from this call (wait for the next readyRead() signal)
    serial->readLine(dataBuffer, 6)

    /* do whatever you want with dataBuffer here */

    if(serial->bytesAvailable() > 0) //if there are still unread bytes
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "serialReciver", Qt::QueuedConnection); //call function again as if readyRead() signal was emitted
}
```

P.S this answer assumes that the input is guaranteed to be always like this: 4 chars of digits then a newline then 4 chars of digits then a newline again, etc. . . So if it did not follow this pattern, then this will cause undefined behavior.

P.S I did not fix your typo in *`serialReciver`*.

Comment: Your solution work's pretty well, but for 4 digit numbers, if i counting below the 1000 rpm's and i got values like 800-700, i got newlines too..

Comment: edited the answer, should be working now for all values that have 4 digits or less. . .

Comment: @RoStel , in order for it to work with numbers with more than 4 digits just enlarge the `dataBuffer` and edit the call to `readLine`. . .